# Is this the optimal way to validate an only 0 and 1 string input?

Tags: java, string, validation

I have an input where user must introduce a binary 16 bit sequence...
So I wrote this code to validate the string `bits` and I expect to get 1 when after the validation of a real binary sequence.

However it's really **not working**. I already tried by comparing `if (c != '1' || c!='0')` and got not results.

```
if ( bits.length() != 16 ) return 0;
    char[] toCharArray = bits.toCharArray();

    for (char c : toCharArray) {
        if ( ( Character.getNumericValue(c) != 1 ) || ( Character.getNumericValue(c) != 0 ) ) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return 1;
```

Comment: You forgot some quotes. `if (c != '1' || c!='0')`

Comment: Don't use 0 and 1 to mean false and true. Use the boolean type, and the literals `false` and `true`.

Comment: @MattBall There is no need for the quotes since he's getting the numeric value.

Comment: @MattBall, `Character.getNumericValue` returns an `int`, so the single quotes are incorrect.

Comment: @Maroun & rgettman, I was referring to the original attempt, which I went on to correct in that comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a one-liner:

```
return bits.matches("[01]{16}") ? 1 : 0;
```

It would be even better to use `boolean` for `true` and `false` instead of `1` and `0`.

This is what you would need then:

```
return bits.matches("[01]{16}");
```

Comment: Thanks so much, could you explain a bit the return criteria added on first regular expression?

Comment: The `[]` denote a character class consisting only of zeros and ones, the `{}` denotes the length of the match. See the [Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 4):

Your logic is incorrect.  You need to error out if the value doesn't equal `1` *and* it doesn't equal `0`.  Use `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: God, you're right, I should be ashamed by posting this. Thanks a lot @rgettman success for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your 'if' will always return true, its like saying 
"If its not 5 oclock or its not 6 oclock, do something"

Its always not one of them